# How to display images full size programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview, scale

In my iOS application I want to display images in zoom. When tap the image it should comes to full view and back.

How do I view images in full screen programmatically in iOS?

Answer (score 1):

See the [`contentMode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622619-contentmode) of [`UIImageView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview) as `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` and `UIViewContentModeCenter` in display of images.

Answer (score 0):

Add an imageview for your screen what ever you want, display image on that using

```
imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];
```

if you want back just remove imageview on a button click or timer what ever you wane using

```
[imageview removeFromsuperview];
```